# Default value string.empty in Sqlite table

Tags: sqlite

How can we specify empty string as default value in Sqlite table.
Currently I am using Firefox extension for generating table.
I tried putting '' , but not working.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set default value to empty string for TEXT column?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6598881/how-to-set-default-value-to-empty-string-for-text-column)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

With a [DEFAULT constraint](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html):

```
CREATE TABLE foo(
    ID   INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    Name TEXT    DEFAULT '',
    etc
);
```