# How to set default date value in SQLite during table creation

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, ubuntu, sqlite

Looking for some advice and help. I want to set a column value to default to the current system date, should no date value be inserted into the table. I have tried without success in two different ways. The first is below. Using string formatting and running this code,

```
current_date = datetime.now().strftime('%Y %m %d')
conn = sqlite3.connect("pipe_tally.db")

cur = conn.cursor()

def create_table():
    """This function creates the database table."""
    cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE tally_file (
        pipe_id TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
        kind TEXT,
        joint_num INTEGER,
        heat INTEGER,
        asset_length REAL CHECK(asset_length > 0),
        asset_wall_thickness REAL,
        asset_degree REAL,
        manufacturer TEXT,
        collected_date TEXT DEFAULT {}
        )""".format(current_date))
    conn.commit()
```

Gives me the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 18, in <module>
    main()
  File "main.py", line 11, in main
    db.create_table()
  File "/home/bigdaddy/PAM_Android/db_helper.py", line 25, in create_table
    )""".format(current_date))
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "09": syntax error
```

Which I am guess the 09 is the month but I am not understanding this error.
The second way is trying to use a tuple as below:

```
import sqlite3
from datetime import datetime

current_date = datetime.now().strftime('%Y %m %d')
conn = sqlite3.connect("pipe_tally.db")

cur = conn.cursor()

def create_table():
    """This function creates the database table."""
    cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE tally_file (
        pipe_id TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
        kind TEXT,
        joint_num INTEGER,
        heat INTEGER,
        asset_length REAL CHECK(asset_length > 0),
        asset_wall_thickness REAL,
        asset_degree REAL,
        manufacturer TEXT,
        collected_date TEXT DEFAULT (?)
        )""", (current_date,))
    conn.commit()
```

And running that returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 18, in <module>
    main()
  File "main.py", line 11, in main
    db.create_table()
  File "/home/bigdaddy/PAM_Android/db_helper.py", line 25, in create_table
    )""", (current_date,))
sqlite3.OperationalError: default value of column [collected_date] is not constant
```

Is it possible to accomplish this with SQLite?
I am using Xubuntu Linux 16.04 LTS, Python3.6 and SQLite3 version 2.8.17
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What does "current" refer to, table creation or row insertion?

Comment: @CL. I am wanting "current" to mean during row insertion. Sorry for not clarifying that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are merely missing the two `'`'s in:

```
collected_date TEXT DEFAULT '{}'
```

Code below runs without error:

```
from datetime import datetime
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
cur = conn.cursor()

current_date = datetime.now().strftime('%Y %m %d')
command = """CREATE TABLE tally_file (
        collected_date TEXT DEFAULT '{}'
        )""".format(current_date)

cur.execute(command)
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

There is a similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6598881/how-to-set-default-value-to-empty-string-for-text-column)

In general, it is now such a good decision to default the database with today's date at schema creation, un less it is a very speciifc task (eg. the database lives very shortly). You get a cleaner result with default value on insert, I guess.

Comment: Thanks @ Evgeny Pogrebnyak. This works for table creation without error. Now I am aware that I need to implement this at row insertion level though.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the special symbol [CURRENT_DATE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#dfltval) as default value for newly inserted rows:

```sql
CREATE TABLE tally_file (
    [...],
    collected_date TEXT DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE
);
```